# Newton Interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods

Let $K$ be a field. Let $x_0,\dots,x_m$ be destinct elements of $K$. Let $\omega_n$ be the Polynomial $(X-x_0)\cdots(X-x_{n-1})$. Given a function $f\colon K\longrightarrow K$, let

$$a_n=\sum_{j=0}^n\dfrac{f(x_j)}{\displaystyle{\prod_{{\begin{matrix}k=0\\k\not=j\end{matrix}}}^n}(x_j-x_k)}\,.$$

Let $p_m[f;x_0,\dots,x_m]=\sum_{n=0}^ma_n\omega_n$. How can I see that $p_m[f,x_0,\dots,x_m](x_l)=f(x_l)$? Is there some trick to avoid lots of computation? If not, could you help me going the computational way?

Comment: Have you tried induction on $m$ ?

Comment: @Ihf Yes. When performing the induction step, I still have to show the interpolation property for $x_l=x_m$ so this did not seem like a simplification to me.